# Expected status code in (200-299), got 500

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, afnetworking

I'm fetching data from server. Server side is maintaining from client. I'm just parsing the data and get using AFNetworking. But may be some SOAPACtion having error.Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://test.server.com/Role

HTTP POST:

```
POST /service/services.asmx/Role HTTP/1.1
Host: server.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

SyncResetData=string
```

Code:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<Sync_Reset_Role xmlns=\"http://test.server.com/\">\n"
                             "<SyncResetData><![CDATA[%@]]></SyncResetData>\n"
                             "</Sync_Reset_Role>\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n",string];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/services.asmx?wsdl/Role",SERVICE_ENDPOINT]];


     NSLog(@"url is getResetRoleContentLength %@",url);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *strLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];

    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.server.com/Role"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue: strLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


         AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2 = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation2 setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2, id responseObject2) {


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);


        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestFailed)]){
            [delegate performSelector:@selector(requestFailed)];
        }


    }];
```

Error:

```
 Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500" UserInfo=0x6995430 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://test.server.com/Role.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x693c870>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://test.server.com/test/services.asmx?wsdl/Role, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 500, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest http://test.server.com/test/services.asmx?wsdl/Role>}
```

Comment: What were the changes?

Comment: and what is the question? at least tell us what are the changes.

Comment: my first guess is that the xml you post is broken as you create the XML using stringWithFormat which is a horrible idea (probably some escaping going wrong)

Comment: One mistake is that your `content-type` is incorrect - you are stating that you are sending data using URL encoding (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), but you are actually sending XML.